# ssh setup config file but I don't know the values to set in it

Tags: git, github, ssh, config

When I try to clone a rep there's an error saying that my config file has errors. Here is the config file:

```
Host dev
  HostName Sundae
  user.name =
  user.email =
```

for obvious reasons I removed the values but there is the name and the mail typed between double quotes.

Someone told me that if I delete the config file then try to git clone it would generate the config file but it's not the case. I deleted my SSH key in both the computer and GitHub settings to create another one and same the config file is still lacking plus it won't git now that there's no config file.

I found some informations on the internet, including a stack overflow question for my problem but it's for windows. I found another article saying there's a command for generating a config file but the command asks for the values (port, hostname) that I don't have and don't know how to get. Can someone help me please?

Comment: What do you mean by "the config file"? What you posted seems to be a mixture of a `ssh_config` and the git configuration (the `Host`/`HostName` part belongs in `ssh_config` while the `user.name` and `user.email` belongs in git config). Also the `user.email` and `user.name` don't become relevant until you *create your own commits*. They don't influence the cloning of an existing git repository at all. My suggestion: remove those two lines only.

Comment: Note: the [tag:linux] tag is for programming at the Linux-system-call level, e.g., calling `open`, `preadv`, `unlink`, and the like, not for using utilities that happen to run *on* Linux.

Answer (score 0):

An [SSH config file structure and pattern](https://linuxize.com/post/using-the-ssh-config-file/#ssh-config-file-structure-and-patterns) is only composed of SSH options:

```
Host hostname1
    SSH_OPTION value
    SSH_OPTION value
```

Like:

```
Host targaryen
    HostName 192.168.1.10
    User daenerys
    Port 7654
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/targaryen.key
```

Anything which is not SSH-related should be removed.